# Css bootstrap div width has decimal value

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

having following `html` structure, `My Content` div has a decimal witdh  (e.g 319.98px width) in some viewports.

The wrapper has a `max-width: 960px`.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        My content 
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to avoid decimal width here?

Comment: from memory, bootstrap uses percentage based widths, with static px guttering. The problem is that there is a limit to the length of a recurring percentage, (for sanities sake) `0.33333...` or `1/3`. So `960 * 0.33333...` will likely result in a non-perfect integer. Is there a reason that the decimal is an issue?

Comment: A. `How to avoid decimal width here` Why? B. Give the parent div (`row`) fix  width which divide by 3.

Comment: use `calc()`:  I.e. `calc( 99% / 3 )` will calculate expression and round up  result.

Comment: @haxxxton the decimal value was an issue while I was trying to put another absolute position div upon this, and jquery rounds up.
Vanilla js makes the position possible, but I wondered if this is a normal thing

Comment: @xhallix, if you absolutely position a box that was `960px` wide and then add your `row` and `col-xs-4` divs inside it, they should align nicely, that or potentially place the absolute positioned div INSIDE the decimal div and it should cover it. If you post what you're trying to do to a http://jsfiddle.net id be happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the decimal width with javascript/jQuery and horizontally align "My Content" div using CSS

jQuery

```
var my-content-width = $('.my-content').width(); // get width of content

width = width.round(); // remove decimal
```

CSS

```
.my-content {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```